# How to adjust font awesome down arrow via css

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm using font awesome and I'm using one of the down arrows next to some text to indicate a dropdown but the arrow is very low next to the adjust and I would like to be able to raise the arrow but can't seem to figure out how.

Here is a fiddle of what I"m using
http://jsfiddle.net/bns77e8t/

```
<span>Would like down arrow to be raised a bit</span> <i class="fa fa-sort-desc">
```

If you look at the fiddle you'll see the arrow is very low next to the text and I tried using negative margin but it doesn't seem like it has any effect on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need more precise control, try using `position: relative` and adjust the `top` offset, for example:

```css
i {
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span>Would like down arrow to be raised a bit</span> <i class="fa fa-sort-desc">
```

Comment: Thank you, vertical align will do for this instance but that precise rule will come in hand down the road, i didn't think to set it to relative.

Comment: Always good to have several options to solve a design problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try vertical-align: baseline or top on the arrow or text. It depends on what you like more. 
There are some more values possible. Just try them out or google them.

Edit: I tried top as value, which looks good to me.